# Retrieving Youtube comments with fullscreen/yt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt to interact with Youtube API, but after a couple of hours of testing I'm unable to fetch comments from a video.

I suspect the reason is I'm requesting the wrong permissions, but I can't find anything clear in Google docs about what scope to ask. I appears from the OAuth playground it's https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
but still, I'm not able to make it work.

This is the omniauth provider line to request a new token:

```
  provider :google_oauth2, key, secret, {:scope => 'http://gdata.youtube.com,email,profile,youtube,youtube.force-ssl'}
```

And this is how I try to retrieve the comments:

```
Yt.configure do |config|
    config.client_id = key
    config.client_secret = secret
end
youtube_client = Yt::Account.new access_token: 'yadayada'
video = Yt::Video.new id: 'foobar', auth: youtube_client
puts video.comments
```

What I get is:

```
Yt::Errors::Forbidden: A request to YouTube API was considered forbidden by the server:
{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"insufficientPermissions", "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}}
```

I've tried pretty much the same on channels too, same problem, that's why I guessed there's something wrong with my access_token.

Has someone done this? What am I doing wrong? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on the page you have shared the link of, I am not able to see this line of code:

```
account = Yt::Account.new authorization_code: '4/Ja60jJ7_Kw0', redirect_uri: redirect_uri
```

***Every user who authorizes your app will be redirected to the redirect_uri with an extra code parameter that looks something like 4/Ja60jJ7_Kw0. Just pass the code to the following method to authenticate and initialize the account:***

If this does not workout try Configuring with environment variables

As an alternative to the approach above, you can configure your app with variables. Setting the following environment variables:

```
export YT_CLIENT_ID="1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export YT_CLIENT_SECRET="1234567890"
export YT_API_KEY="123456789012345678901234567890"
```

is equivalent to configuring your app with the initializer:

```
Yt.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = '1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  config.client_secret = '1234567890'
  config.api_key = '123456789012345678901234567890'
end
```

so use the approach that you prefer. If a variable is set in both places, then Yt.configure takes precedence.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: It's not clear what is the 'authorization_code' mentioned in the docs. Does it mean I can replace '4/Ja60jJ7_Kw0' with any symbols I like or I have to get it somewhere in the Google developers console?